# oracle how to generate a list of period from a list of date

Tags: oracle, date

i would like to write a query to transform a list of date

| list of date |
| --- |
| 15/02/2021 |
| 12/04/2021 |
| 28/07/2021 |
| 31/08/2021 |

to a list of period

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 15/02/2021 | 11/04/2021 |
| 12/04/2021 | 27/07/2021 |
| 28/07/2021 | 31/08/2021 |

Is it possible to do it in a oracle query ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant 1:

```sql
select * 
from (
  select
    dt as dt_start, 
    case when lead(dt,2)over(order by dt) is not null 
      then lead(dt)over(order by dt)-1
      else lead(dt)over(order by dt)
    end as dt_end
  from t
)
where dt_end is not null;
```

Full test with test data:

```sql
alter session set nls_date_format='dd/mm/yyyy';
with t(dt) as (
  select to_date('15/02/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select to_date('12/04/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select to_date('28/07/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select to_date('31/08/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual
)
select * 
from (
  select
    dt as dt_start, 
    case when lead(dt,2)over(order by dt) is not null 
      then lead(dt)over(order by dt)-1
      else lead(dt)over(order by dt)
    end as dt_end
  from t
)
where dt_end is not null;

DT_START   DT_END
---------- ----------
15/02/2021 11/04/2021
12/04/2021 27/07/2021
28/07/2021 31/08/2021
```

Variant 2: match_recognize (Oracle 12+):

```sql
select
  dt_start,dt_end
from t
match_recognize(
  order by dt
  MEASURES 
     prev(dt) as dt_start,
     nvl2(next(dt),e.dt-1,e.dt) as dt_end
  all rows per match
  PATTERN (e+) 
  DEFINE 
    e AS dt > prev(dt)
);
```

Full example with test data:

```sql
with t(dt) as (
  select to_date('15/02/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select to_date('12/04/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select to_date('28/07/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select to_date('31/08/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual
)
select
  dt_start,dt_end
from t
match_recognize(
  order by dt
  MEASURES 
     prev(dt) as dt_start,
     nvl2(next(dt),e.dt-1,e.dt) as dt_end
  all rows per match
  PATTERN (e+) 
  DEFINE 
    e AS dt > prev(dt)
);

DT_START   DT_END
---------- ----------
15/02/2021 11/04/2021
12/04/2021 27/07/2021
28/07/2021 31/08/2021
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9f9e256762c87e67ce3783f51f8d7c8): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9f9e256762c87e67ce3783f51f8d7c8

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what I'm looking for !
thanks !

I've just changed few things because I'm in Oracle 10g probably

```
with t as (
  select to_date('15/02/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
  select to_date('12/04/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select to_date('28/07/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  select to_date('31/08/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual
)
select * 
from (
  select
    dt as dt_start, 
    case when lead(dt,2)over(order by dt) is not null 
      then lead(dt)over(order by dt)-1
      else lead(dt)over(order by dt)
    end as dt_end
  from t
)
where dt_end is not null;
```